# How to skip first N tests in PHPUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

The scenario: run a huge batch of tests with PHPUnit and some test (say 537 of 1544) fails after many minutes. The change is small and unlikely to effect the previous tests, I'd like to be able to skip the first 536 tests doing something like this to "pick up where I left off":

```
phpunit --skip=536
```

Of course I will run all tests eventually, but right now, I don't want to have to wait many minutes to get back to the broken test(s). I know I can run a single suite but that is tedious/unhelpful if several dozen suites remain to be tested.

Is there a way? Or something even close?

Comment: Not related to your question but unit tests must not take "several minutes" to run, goes against their purpose to run frequently :)

Comment: It's possible we disagree on terminology and I'm happy to be corrected, but the problem remains, when I run all tests it takes about an hour and I don't see any reason to remove tests.

Comment: You shouldn't need to remove tests but you just may have some that can be optimized by mocking external systems (Database, webservice, etc) that can be related to speed of your tests.  Ideally your entire test suite should be able to run in under 5 minutes (and that is on the long end).  There are probably some optimizations that you can do to speed that up but it isn't completely related to your question as @ClaudioRedi mentioned.

Comment: This feature would be super useful. I wonder if there are any other ways to solve it without using `filter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `--filter` option to select which tests that you want to run.  There is also the `--testsuite` option which you can use to specify.  Both of these options take a pattern parameter that is used to select the tests that you are running.

The `--testsuite` option does require that you have the test suites created in a `phpunit.xml` file in order to work.

There is also the [`@group` annotation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.group) that can be used in your tests and then would be able to use `--group` and `--exclude-group` to either include the group or not respectively.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of these features but neither of them addresses the use case I asked about, at least directly.

Comment: I ended up using the `--filter` option as a close enough work around. E.g. `--filter "^[n-z]"` does the "second half" of the tests.