# Resuming PHPUnit test in Moodle from specific percentage or test number

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, moodle

I am running PHPUnitTest (vendor/bin/phpunit) on Moodle, it took about 30 min and reached (2867 / 4261) 68% and break with fatal error. 
[image]

I have fixed the fatal error, now I wish to continue/resume from 68% or 2867/4261(where it broke last time) rather than running from beginning or running each test one by one.

Any possibility?

I am following guideline [here](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/PHPUnit#What_is_PHPUnit)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711469/how-to-skip-first-n-tests-in-phpunit